# Conditional logic in Salesforce Text Email Template

Tags: email-template, formula-field

I want to add conditional logic to my text email template.

Here is what I tried:

```
Destination__c = {!Enquiry__c.Destination__c}

{!IF("{!Enquiry__c.Destination__c}" = "Barcelona", "i am barcelona", "i am not barcelona")}
```

When I sent a test message, I got the following:

```
Destination__c = Barcelona 

i am not barcelona
```

I'm aware of formula fields, but I'd rather have the logic in the template.  Although, if I need to make a formula field, I'm willing to do so.

Comment: `{!IF(Enquiry__c.Destination__c == "Barcelona", "i am barcelona", "i am not barcelona")}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
{!CASE(Enquiry__c.Destination__c, "Barcelona", "i am barcelona", "i am not barcelona")}
```

If that doesn't work with a simple Text Email Template, try re-creating as a Custom HTML Email Template, it should work.

Comment: formula works best, custom email template has some disadvantages to keep editable text before sending.

Comment: It worked!  Thanks, iDog.  The reason why I don't want to use formula fields is because I want to conditionally show a sentence depending on the value of `Destination__c`.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional logic only works correctly if you use Visualforce Email Template.

For, Text or HTML based email templates, you need to create a formula field which will return results based on your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this once -

```
{!IF({!Enquiry__c.Destination__c} == "Barcelona", "i am barcelona", "i am not barcelona")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{!Enquiry__c.Destination__c}` with `Enquiry__c.Destination__c`

```
{!IF(Enquiry__c.Destination__c == "Barcelona", "i am barcelona", "i am not barcelona")}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This looks more like it should be a comment on (or an edit to) another answer, rather than an answer by itself. Usually, a good answer will go into detail about _what_ the problem is (in this case, an extra `{!}` in the formula), _how_ to fix it, and _why_ the fix works. Normally, new users aren't able to comment on other people's questions/answers (50 reputation required), but since you linked your account from other SE sites, you have 100 reputation. I'm recommending a deletion for this one.